# Can someone help me with the sentence structure here as I cannot understand

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verbs, present-perfect

It would be great if you would not be here around for a while.
Is this sentence correct?
This is I guess if clause or conditional clause

Comment: It's an awkward sentence. The English expression that you are looking for in this context is **to make yourself scarce**. It would be great if you would make yourself scarce for a while - or go away for a while. Yes, the speaker's anticipated pleasure is conditional on the person going away.

Answer (score 1):

> > It would be great if you would not be here around for a while.

No, that is not correct. First of all let's switch two words:

> > It would be great if you would not be around here for a while.

That is doable but awkward. Better would be:

> > It would be great if you would not hang around here for a while.

The problem is that the verb 'be' is not usually seen as something you 'do'... and your sentence is asking the person to 'do' something (or not do it). So you need a 'doing' verb, not a 'being' verb. Usually.